# how to use CascadeClassifier in VS 2010 OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I have a project, what loads pics, etc. I want to make object detection. I've got an xml from haartrain. The following code however **won't compile:**

```
String berniurl= "D:\Dropbox\Egyetem\tanulmany2\kutyafelek\berni.xml";
CascadeClassifier berni_cascade;

if( !berni_cascade.load( berniurl ) ){ 
    printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); 
};
```

VS2010, OpenCV2.2 (downloaded from site already built).

and errors are in main.obj, like:

```
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::CascadeClassifier::~CascadeClassifier(void)" (??1CascadeClassifier@cv@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main   C:\Users\Gabor\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\opencvcucc\opencvcucc\main.obj


Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall cv::CascadeClassifier::load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?load@CascadeClassifier@cv@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main C:\Users\Gabor\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\opencvcucc\opencvcucc\main.obj
```

Comment: Make sure that you have run all the steps from http://www.anlak.com/using-opencv-2-3-1-with-visual-studio-2010-tutorial/ ( I think this tutorial is better than http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B_VS2010 )

Comment: thanks! I was missing a few dependencies in libs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As banuj said, I missed some imports. helper site: [anlak.com/using-opencv-2-3-1-with-visual-studio-2010-tutorial](http://anlak.com/using-opencv-2-3-1-with-visual-studio-2010-tutorial)